# Different SHA-1 keys in google play app integrity - which ones to use?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, google-oauth, facebook-authentication

When running eas credentials, I have same keys for development and production. When I go to google play console, I have different keys.  "Upload key certificate"  shows same key (both SHA-1 and SHA-256. "App signing key certificate" shows different keys. I need the keys on multiple places- google auth and facebook auth I need to use the SHA-1. Which one I use? Does it matter if im in development (running the development build) or not (using also internal testing with production build). Thanks!!!